# React - zIndex does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

My React App with Autocomplete function is not yet complete.
Please help to verify my code.

[image]

For the following code, I add the search box with className autocomplete style. when I type it show that autocomplete not overlap the table.
I try to add both z-index in css and zIndex in react code but it is still not working.

```
render() {
        const list = this.state.items.map((item) => <li key={item._id} style={{zIndex: 99}}>{item.itemname}</li>);
    return (
      <div className="Receivings">
        <h1>Receivings</h1>
        <hr />
        <Row>
            <Col xs={8} sm={4} md={3} lg={2}>
                <div className="autocomplete" style={{zIndex: 10}}>
                    <input 
                        style={{zIndex: 10}}
                        type="text" 
                        className="autocomplete" 
                        placeholder="Search"    
                        onChange={this.getItemName}
                    />
                    <ul style={{zIndex: 10}}>{list}</ul>
                </div>

              </Col>
            </Row>
            <div className="panel panel-default" style={{ zIndex: -1 }}>
                <table className="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Item ID</th>
                    <th>Item Name</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Wholesale Price</th>
                    <th>Retail Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Comment</th>
                    <th />
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {this.state.pageOfItems.map(item => (
                        <tr key={item._id}>
                                <td>{item.itemid}</td>
                                <td>{item.itemname}</td>
                                <td>{item.category}</td>
                                <td style={{textAlign: "right"}}>{item.wholesaleprice.toLocaleString(navigator.language, { minimumFractionDigits: 2 })}</td>
                                <td style={{textAlign: "right"}}>{item.retailprice.toLocaleString(navigator.language, { minimumFractionDigits: 2 })}</td>
                                <td style={{textAlign: "right"}}>{item.quantitystock}</td>
                                <td>{item.comment}</td>
                                <td>
                                <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" onClick={() => this.props.history.push(`${this.props.match.url}/edit/${item._id}`)}></i>
                        </td>
                              </tr>
                            ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <Pagination
            items={this.state.items}
            onChangePage={this.onChangePage}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: why both of zIndex are 10 ?

Comment: I have tried a lot. Any suggestion, please. Just want to put the table under the autocomplete.

Comment: positioning autocomplete in absolute? i think it overlap the table if you make a position:absolute;

Comment: Hi Roy, Thank you very much. It's working!!!!

Comment: That is not a react problem. You should take a deeper look on how z-index and stacking context works.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By default, all HTML elements have an implicit `position: static`.

If you want to apply any of the 2d co-ordinates:

- `top`
- `right`
- `bottom`
- `left`

or the 3d co-ordinate:

- `z-index`

then you **must** explicitly declare a different kind of positioning.

Either:

- `position: relative;`
- `position: absolute;`
- `position: fixed;`
- `position: sticky;`

Answer (score 2):

Give position absolute to your ul in which you are showing result